# WordPress PHP flag if any posts get published

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to keep an application scope variable which will be set to TRUE every time any new or modified posts get published.

```
$GLOBALS["NewPostsPublished"] = TRUE;
```

based on this flag, I can use query_posts() inside a page template through a WP page to get some most recent posts.
So far I haven't found any plug-ins and 'events' to handle that.

What would be the best approach to keep such a flag?

Comment: do you want this because to get most recent post?

Comment: @jogesh_pi that's correct. to get recently updated posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'publish_post_update' );

function publish_post_update( $post_id ) {

    if ( get_post_status ( get_the_id() ) == 'publish' ) {

        update_post_meta(get_the_id(),'NewPostsPublished','True');

    }

}
```

You will then be able to query posts by meta_key `NewPostsPublished` where meta_value = `True`

Comment: Actually, I end up using "publish_post" and "transition_post_status" (checking if status is changed from published to non-published).